# Clicking on Application shortcut throws unknown publisher warning

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsinstaller

I have installed my windows forms application setup on a windows 7 machine. The shortcut for the application appears on the desktop. When I click on this shortcut the Windows 7 **unknown publisher warning** appears although I have signed my exe with a security certificate. During installation the publisher name appears fine. But when I execute the app using the shortcut the warning always says "**Unknown Publisher**". I have used Visual Studio installer setup to create the setup.exe for my application. Is there any way that I can put my company name in place of the unknown publisher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Had to sign the project output in Appname\obj\x86\Debug folder  and then add in to the Visual Studio Installer setup project and then build the setup project.